# How can I simplify this list?

Tags: python, list, slice

List slicing was never my strongest aspect in Python, and I'm at a bit of a loss.

```
for x in range(1, width-1):
  for y in range(1, height-1):
    temp, walls = [], 0
    temp = [[ grid[x-1][y-1], grid[x][y-1], grid[x+1][y-1] ],
            [ grid[x-1][y], '@', grid[x+1][y] ],
            [ grid[x-1][y+1], grid[x][y+1], grid[x+1][y+1] ]]
for l in temp: walls += l.count('#')
```

This is part of my code for cellular automata map generation for a simple roguelike.  That long ugly statement can be simplified, somehow.  I thought that `temp = [ grid[x-1::3][y-1], grid[x-1::3][y], grid[x-1::3][y+1] ]` would work, but I get index out of range errors.

Comment: You used a step size of 3. Maybe you meant `x-1:x+2:1`? (start, stop, step). But I'm confused by your slicing in a 2d context. You might want to play around in the interpreter to see if it's even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want:

```
temp = [l[y-1:y+2] for l in grid[x-1:x+2]] # extract local data
temp[1][1] = "@" # replace centre
walls = sum(l.count("#") for l in temp) # count walls
```

The slices you are trying to use:

```
l[n::3]
```

would take every third item from index `n` of `l` to the end; the arguments to slices are, as with `range`, `[start:stop:step]`.

Comment: I completely forgot how python works; I see why it wasn't working now.  Thank you!